# Symmetrical Components in time function equation representation

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

I have equation which I can not understand until end, so your help I would appreciate.
I start with equation No. 1 which is clear:
The relations between the phase quantities $ \underline G_r,\underline G_s,\underline G_t $ and symmetrical components $\underline G_0,\underline G_1,\underline G_2 $ are given by
$$
   \begin{bmatrix}
    \underline G_0\\
    \underline G_1\\
    \underline G_2\\ 
    \end{bmatrix} = 1/3  \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 1 & 1 \\
    1 & a & a^2 \\
    1 & a^2 & a \\
    \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
    \underline G_r\\
    \underline G_s\\
    \underline G_t\\ 
    \end{bmatrix} \tag{1}
$$
where $a = e^{j\frac{2\pi}3}$  and $a^2 = e^{j\frac{4\pi}3}$ are phase rotating operators.

Equation No.2 which is clear as well: The time functions of the phase quantities $q_r,q_s,q_t$
$$g_r = \widehat g_r \cos(\omega t + \varphi_r )\\
g_s = \widehat g_s \cos(\omega t + \varphi_s )\\
g_t = \widehat g_t \cos(\omega t + \varphi_t ) \tag{2}
$$
Equation No. 3: corresponding complex phasors are given by
$$ \underline G_r = \widehat g_r e^{j\varphi_r} \\
\underline G_s = \widehat g_s e^{j\varphi_s}  \\
\underline G_t = \widehat g_t e^{j\varphi_t} \tag{3}
$$

From equations (2) and (3) it follows that the time function can be found according to: Equation No. 4
$$ g_i(t) = Re[\underline G_i e^{j\omega t}] = \frac{1}{2}[\underline G_i e^{j\omega t} + \underline G_i^* e^{-j\omega t} ]\tag{4}$$

Applying expressions (3) to (1) and using equation (4) it can be found equation No. 5 which I can not get: 
$$ 3 g_1 = \widehat g_r \cos(\omega t + \varphi_r ) -\frac{1}{2}[\widehat g_s \cos(\omega t + \varphi_s ) + \widehat g_t \cos(\omega t + \varphi_t )] -\frac{\sqrt {3} }{2}[\widehat g_s \sin(\omega t + \varphi_s ) - \widehat g_t \sin(\omega t + \varphi_t ]  \tag{5}$$

I can not get this Equation No.5. I don't understand from where these $\sin$ functions came?

Comment: What is $g_1$ ?

Comment: Please choose a more expressive title.

Comment: $g_1$ is from Equation No. 1 $\underline G_1$. It's small letter just because it represents time functions while big letter represents phasors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $$3\underline G_1 = \underline G_r + a\underline G_s + a^2\underline G_t = \widehat q_r e^{\varphi_r}  + \widehat q_s e^{j(\varphi_s+2\pi/3)} + \widehat q_t e^{j(\varphi_t-2\pi/3)}.$$
Consequently, 
\begin{align}
3\Re{\left[\underline G_1 e^{j w t}\right]} & = \Re{\left[\widehat q_r e^{\varphi_r+wt}  + \widehat q_s e^{j(\varphi_s+wt+2\pi/3)} + \widehat q_t e^{j(\varphi_t+wt-2\pi/3)}\right]} \\
&  = \widehat q_r \cos(wt + \varphi_r) + \widehat q_s \cos(wt + \varphi_s +2\pi/3) + \widehat q_t \cos(wt + \varphi_t-2\pi/3).
\end{align}
Now use $$\cos(\theta \pm a) = \cos(\theta)\cos(a) \mp \sin(\theta) \sin(a)$$ to get the final result.

Comment: Thank you a lot for an answr and especially for such a quick response! Awesome